# Ng Bootstrap calendar, customizing layout

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng bootstrap to get two calendars where I can select a range from.
This is the code:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp ngModel (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t">
```

```
<ng-template #t let-date="date" let-focused="focused">
    <span class="custom-day"
          [class.focused]="focused"
          [class.range]="isFrom(date) || isTo(date) || isInside(date) || isHovered(date)"
          [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
          (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
          (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null">
      {{ date.day }}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
```

But this has its own layout and I can't access the HTML to change it based on my needs.
This is what the default looks like :

[Default Calendar Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTrZh.png)

And what I need to have is this in the header, both sides is this:

[Custom Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfwJd.png)

Is there a way to do this ? How does one normally change such things on ng-bootstrap ?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Of course you can access the HTML (node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation.js and node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation-select.js) . NOT, seriously, you can modify the css to acheive you want. Remember you can use /deep/, e.g. ngb-pagination  /deep/ .customselect{ background:none;-webkit-appearance: visible;
-moz-appearance: visible;
appearance: visible;}

Comment: Thank you so much ,But I need the months to be a select option,and also the year.  Can I also change that ?
I'm really uncertain about how to manipulate with it :|

Comment: I revised the css, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

the "key" is override the class. In your case you can use in your component.css

```
    :host /deep/ ngb-datepicker .custom-select{
      -webkit-appearance: caret;
      -moz-appearance: caret;
      appearance: caret;
      background:none;
    }

    :host /deep/ ngb-datepicker .btn-link {
        display: none;
    }        
//If we surrender about "caret" I suppose we can add this css
    :host /deep/ ngb-datepicker .btn-link {
        display: none;
    }

    :host /deep/ ngb-datepicker ngb-datepicker-navigation-select {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    :host /deep/ ngb-datepicker .custom-select {
        background: #fff url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3E%3Cpath stroke='%23333' stroke-width='.5' fill='none' d='M 1 1 L 2.5 5 L 4 1'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat right .75rem center
        width: 48% !important;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this in my css but nothing changed

Comment: working in Chrome, IE and FireFox, Angular 5 and Angular 4.3. you have a component.ts, with  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css'], and mycomponent.component.css with the css before. I don't figure out what it's wrong.

Comment: I also don't know. Literally nothing shows from this style.
But I added this appearances on the elements on inspect mode, and it's not what I need.
Sure you can hide the buttons and the header.
But the actual months, can't be made into dropdowns by just setting appearance to caret.
Cuz the point was not only to have the month LOOK like a dropdown. They'd have to be functional when clicking. That I didn't know how to change the default.

Comment: I add SVG background